# How can I search for multiple words in one function?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've a macro that searches for a word ("January") and converts the space next to it to a protected space.

I'd like to search for the other months of the year as well. Is there a way of searching for the other months within the same function, rather than copying my code 11 times, searching for a different month each time?

I'm only interested in changing the search text line, if possible, as the rest works.

I have another search function that does the same but following any digit ("([0-9])") and that works, I just want to shorten 12 potential search functions into one.

```vb
Sub ProtectedSpacesAfterMonths()

Dim sFindText As String
sFindText = "January "
Selection.Find.Execute sFindText
Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.TypeBackspace
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Selection.Find.Execute
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me.

It starts by putting the month names in an array. In a loop on the array, each name is sent to the procedure `FindMonths`, along with the `Range` object to be searched. Putting the code that needs to be repeated in its own procedure saves needing to type it out.

Note how the `Find` process works with a `Range` (rather than `Selection` object). Generally, following what's happening is more reliable with a range than with a selection.

Note, also, how after one "found" has been processed the `Range` is set to extend from the point after it's found one instance of a month to the end of the document. This ensures that all, and not just the first, instance of a month is located.

```
Sub ProcessMonths()
    Dim sFindText As String
    Dim aMonths As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    aMonths = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", _
                    "September", "October", "November", "December")
    For i = LBound(aMonths) To UBound(aMonths)
        sFindText = aMonths(i)
        FindMonths sFindText, ActiveDocument.content
    Next
End Sub

Sub FindMonths(month As String, searchRange As Range)
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    bFound = searchRange.Find.Execute(month)
    Do While bFound
        searchRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        searchRange.Delete wdCharacter, 1
        searchRange.Text = Chr(160)
        searchRange.End = searchRange.Document.content.End
        bFound = searchRange.Find.Execute(month)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For Each sounds like a good move forward. Here's a sample of how I'd put your code (untested) into a For Each block looping over an array of the months of the year.

```
Dim item As Variant
Dim months(1 To 2) as String
Dim str As String

months(1) = "January ": months(2) = "February "

For Each item In months
    Selection.Find.Execute item
    Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.TypeBackspace
        Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
        Selection.Find.Execute
    Loop
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I gave your code a go (all I changed was 'months(1 To 12)' and added the remaining months) and it worked! I used it on an example letter with a few dates in it, and some worked. I then added a list of examples (one date from each month, with different dates and years e.e. 1 January 2000, 3 February 2010 etc) to test if it's anything to do with the month that doesn't work, but every instance in that list worked. I can't figure out why some didn't, there's no difference in them from the ones that did work.

Comment: Okay, after further testing, it seems to work better when months are in their right sequence.In my example letter, the original has four dates in this order: October 2019, December 1974, November 2019, October 2019. Without changing anything, only the two October 2019s work. When changing December 1974 to October 1974, that one works, but the first October 2019 doesn't. When changing them to this order: September 2019, October 1974, November 2019, December 2019, they all work. When changing them to December 2019, November 1974, October 2019, September 2019, only September works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create an array of months and then loop through that array for each. Simply:

```vb
Dim arrMonths() As Variant
Dim i As Long

arrMonths = Array("Jan", "Feb", ..., "Dec")

For i = LBound(arrMonths) To UBound(arrMonths)
    sFindText = arrMonths(i)
    Selection.Find.Execute sFindText
    Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.TypeBackspace
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Loop
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this second as I know nothing about arrays or "LBound"/"UBound", and I got the exact same result as Kade M.'s suggestion.